# Geodataframe.to_postgis() with Flask and tracking SQLAlchemy Models

Tags: python, geopandas, geoalchemy, sqlalchemy

I have the following situation:
My application front end will receive a shapefile input and have to save it to a PostGIS database.
After that, the application backend will start a series of tasks that will have to track the recently inserted geometry and other Model attributes.

For example:

User input a shapefile containing a polygon.

Save that polygon to postgis table

Start performing GIS operations such as Intersections, Overlays, etc. These operations will produce new geometries wich will be saved in another tables, but having to track back to the first inserted geometry foreign key(first_inserted_polygon.id)

**Question**

Using geopandas Geodataframe.to_postgis(), I was able to succesfully insert the inputs into the database, but how exactly do I keep track of Models Id's and attributes of those inserted geometries using SQLAlchemy Models?

I know it's fairly easy to do that with non-geometry Models, but in this specific case I'm kind of stuck here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured that out using Geoalchemy2.

For those facing similar problem, this is what worked for me:

```
class AreaModel(db.Model):    
    __tablename__ = 'initial_areas'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name_area = db.Column(db.String(100))
    area = db.Column(db.Float(precision=2))
    geometry = db.Column(Geometry('MULTIPOLYGON', 3857))


    protected_reserve = db.relationship('ProtectedReserve', backref='protected')
    pol = db.column_property(func.ST_AsText(geometry))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<AreaModel %s>' % self.id
```

So for adding the geometry coming from geopandas using SQLAlchemy Model instead of geopandas GeoDataFrame.to_postgis() method, simply use geoalchemy2 WKTElement class

```
import geopandas as gpd
from geoalchemy2 import WKTElement

gdf = gpd.read_file('.......')   

for geom in gdf.geometry: 
            area1 = AreaModel(name_area='Some Name', area=5555.002, geometry=WKTElement(geom, gdf.crs.to_epsg()))            
            db.session.add(area1)
            db.session.commit()
```